# Java Enum on a switch statement

Tags: java, enums, this, switch-statement, enumeration

I have this piece of code right here , I really don't get it why is that there is a "this" keyword in the switch statement, take a look at this code

```
public enum InstrumentType{

    GUITAR,BANJO,MANDOLIN,DOBRO, FIDDLE ,BASS,

    public String toString(){
        switch(this){
        case GUITAR:
            return "Guitar";
        case BANJO: 
            return "Banjo";
        case DOBRO:
            return "Dobro";
        case FIDDLE:
            return "Fiddle";
        case BASS:
            return "Bass";
        case MANDOLIN:
            return "Mandolin";
        default: 
            return "Unspecified";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here **this** refers to the current **InstrumentType** value

```
static void MyFunc( )
{
    InstrumentType f = InstrumentType.GUITAR;
    String s = f.toString();
}
```

When `f.toString()` is invoked. **this** will have **GUITAR** value

Comment: can I just use it like this?  InstumentType.GUITAR , rather than doing the String s= f.toString(); ?

Comment: If you notice the case of the enum is all UPPERCASE but the returned string is not. If you want to return the enum as it is declared you don't need to define a toString method

Comment: yes I did notice, but i was expecting if I do InstrumentType.GUITAR, it would automatically throw back "Guitar"

Comment: Instrument.GUITAR is a enum value. Instrument.GUITAR.toString() will be a String

Comment: Also please try to accept more of your answers. Lot of them seem to be answered correctly but you have not accepted any answers

Comment: okay I tested this again, I used System.out.println(InstrumentType.GUITAR); why did it gave me "Guitar"?

Comment: Read http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print(java.lang.Object) which mentions print will eventually use the obj.toString method

Answer (score 1):

It refers to the current instance.

If you had an anum instance "foo":

```
String s = foo.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` points to its container class/struct/enum like elements. in this case, `this` is used for `InstrumentType`. it's a basic rule for most of the OO languages.

Comment: It points to the current instance of the class/enum not the class/enum. That is an important distintion.